# get the value of a variable which is appended at the end of a URL with jquery

Tags: jquery

```
http://domain.com/lookbook/?lookScroll=1
```

I just need to grab the lookScroll variable value from the current URL of the page and store it in a variable with JQuery, how could I do this? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-the-url-parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript